# How to Summary Lists?

Tags: views

Posted by pennyc on December 14, 2014 at 3:21pm

1. I've created a View over a summary of my tags using
   Relationships
   Content: Taxonomy terms on node

Contextual filters
(term) Taxonomy term: Name

and it works well only that I get as first post a category named "Uncategorized" which don't exsist. How did this happend?

2. I'm also doing a summary over some Content Types using
   Contextual filters
   Field: Name

Relationships
Entity Reference: Name

but this time all I get is the ID and number of posts and not the title of the content type. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Can you give me an idea of what you want the 2nd view in your example to display? i.e. Show me all nodes that...?

Comment: This is what happends http://www.pennycentury.com/statistics

Nonw of the 3 views get links correct and in view Arist and view Labels I don'tget the Names but only IDs